# How to Get VALUES from another table into another table in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

First I should say my English is not perfect.
I am using XAMPP 5.6.0.0

I have two tables, `services` and `services_cat`.

```
    -- Table structure for table `services_cat`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `services_cat` 
   (`ser_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `service_category` varchar(50) NOT NULL)

    -- Table structure for table `services`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `services` 
    (`service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `scid` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `service_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `service_statement` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
     `service_photo` varchar(100) NOT NULL)
```

I want to show following data in one table.

```
service_id
ser_cat_id
service_category
service_title
service_statement
```

`ser_cat_id` and `service_id` are `PRIMARY KEY`s.

here `ser_cat_id` save into `scid` in the `services` table. This `ser_cat_id` save multiple times in the `scid` colomn. But `service_title` will be changed. There are different types of `service_title`, but the `scid` is same for that different `service_title`s. That `scid` comming from `ser_cat_id` from `services_cat` table.

I can pass `ser_cat_id` to `scid` from `service_cat` table and I can fetch (display) that `scid`. But I want to display that DISTINCT `service_category` name of the `ser_cat_id`(same as `scid` in `services` table).

Can you please help me ..

Following is my code.

```
    <?php
    include_once("conn.php");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM services_cat JOIN services ON services_cat.ser_cat_id = services.service_id GROUP BY service_category ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
    {

        echo "<tr>
        <td><p class='table-p'>$row->scid</p></td>
        <td><p class='table-p'>$row->ser_cat_id</p></td>
        <td><p class='table-p'>$row->service_category = $row->scid</p></td>
        <td><p class='table-p'>$row->service_title</p></td>
        <td><p class='table-p'>$row->service_statement</p></td>

        <td><p class='table-p'><a href='service_edit.php?ide=$row->service_id'>Edit</a> |
        <a href='service_delete.php?idd=$row->service_id'>Delete</a></p></td>
        ";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: one `ser_cat_id` may have several `service_category` ? otherwise your query is correct. I believe you want to recieve DISTINCT `service_title` not `service_category`

Comment: isn't it `services_cat.ser_cat_id = services.scid` ?

Comment: `ser_cat_id` have many `service_category` 
Ex :: `ser_cat_id` = `1` `service_category` = `Decoration` ,,,,,, `ser_cat_id` = `2` `service_category` = `Dressing` ...... `ser_cat_id` = `3` `service_category` = `Dancing` etc..

Comment: ser_cat_id is the primary key of services_cat.  scid is the related foreign key in services table.  All joins between these tables should use `ON services_cat.ser_cat_id = services.scid`, as @Berriel said.  So, any joined query you do will have the same values for those two fields.

Comment: No .. Output table is not the DB table. Its temporary table to Display Data from the DB tables.

Comment: YES YES .... :)
`scid` and `service_category` colomns are display same data...

Comment: I didn't get that .... sorry :(

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some sample data for each table, and the query result set you expect?

Comment: `scid` coloumn has values `1`, `1`, `1`, `2` and `service_category` coloumn has values `Decoration`, `Dressing`, `Dresses`, `Dancing` ....... 

But I want to Display `scid` coloumn has values `1`, `1`, `1`, `2` equals to `Decoration`, `Decoration`, `Decoration`, `Dressing`...

Comment: I cannot upload images ... :( still restriction that option for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you want, this is what you need:

```
SELECT s.service_id, c.ser_cat_id, c.service_category, s.service_title, s.service_statement 
FROM services_cat AS c 
INNER JOIN services AS s 
  ON c.ser_cat_id = s.scid
```

Check this running example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/013f7/3/0

Inside your loop, your `$row` will have this data, as you need.

```
$row['service_id']
$row['ser_cat_id']
$row['service_category']
$row['service_title']
$row['service_statement']
```

Comment: OUTSTANDING PERFORMANCE Sir Berriel !!!!!! You are the GREAT...
WoooooooooooooW Thats what I Need .... IT's Working ..... 
Outstanding ..... You are Really Great ..... 
Thank You Sooooooo Much :) :) :) 

I get ideas what i missed in my code .. Again 1000 times Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM services_cat JOIN services ON services_cat.ser_cat_id = services.service_id GROUP BY service_category ");
```

to

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM services_cat JOIN services ON services_cat.ser_cat_id = services.scid GROUP BY service_category ");
```

Comment: Then while loop is not working :( .. Only Display 04 items according to `service_category`. Because `service_category` have 04 values.